# Asynchronous scripts execute after deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Ideally, I would like to have all scripts load asynchronously but in the HTML order. As far as I know, `async` doesn't work that way.

With the following attributes, the `general.min.js` and `funcs.min.js` scripts do not run since there is some jQuery within them.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" async="async"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/general.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/funcs.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

I understand that the attribute only affects the download and not the execution of the scripts.

How, then, is it possible to maintain the execution order after download?

Comment: Never put `async="true"` on a library which has dependencies - ie. jQuery. If you want to optimise your JS it's far better to minify and bundle them all together than it is to use deferred loading.

Comment: Unless your library does the loading itself like Dojo.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have that removed in production. I did it because I am trying to reduce render blocking. Then I came across this problem.

Comment: Both `defer` and `async` download scripts asynchronously, but `defer` waits until the DOM is fully parsed and then executes *keeping order intact* (`async` will execute immediately after downloading complete, regardless of order)

Comment: I'd remove it here too, as the issue is that by deferring the execution you are no longer guaranteed that jQuery will be loaded first. Hence you get errors if the dependant scripts load first - as you've discovered. As I mentioned before, minifying/bundling is the most workable JS optimisation for production environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your scripts to download asynchronously yet execute in order, use `defer`. Rendering won't be blocked because script execution won't start until the document is parsed.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/general.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/funcs.min.js" defer></script>
```

On the other hand, `async` will *also download scripts asynchronously*, but each script it executed immediately after downloading finishes. So if you include a small script below a large script, the *small script will download quicker and be executed first*.

**EDIT #2** (EDIT #1 was replaced by #2 for clarity)

The using `defer` scripts makes a lot of sense when *all scripts are loaded in the `<head>` from **external** sources*. The download is async, DOM parsing isn't blocked, and the execution order is maintained. Yay! I will call these the **deferred scripts**.

However, **inline scripts** (`<script>...</script>`) in the `<body>` are downloaded and executed synchronously *during* DOM parsing, so they won't have access to the **deferred scripts** (because those don't execute until *after* DOM parsing).

What if the **inline scripts** need access **library scripts**, such as jQuery or lodash? Obviously, those **library scripts** must be fully downloaded and executed before the **inline scripts** run. This is done by putting the **library scripts** in the `<head>` *without the use of `defer`*. This makes them execute immediately, in order. Note that the **deferred scripts** can also access the **library scripts** because they are loaded even after the the **inline scripts**!

Phew! Here's an example:

```
<head>
    <!-- Executed last: defered scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/general.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts/funcs.min.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Executed first: library scripts, such as jquery, lodash, etc.. -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Executed second: inline scripts -->
    <script>
        $.ready(console.log);
    </script>
</body>
```

Just one addition: **defered scripts** don't need `onload` listeners (or `$.ready`, etc..) *because the DOM is already loaded*!

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said, deferring libraries is bad. I had some script tags in the body of the document which weren't executing because jQuery was deferred.

Comment: **Note:** "_script tags without async or defer_" is not possible since `async` and `defer` require an external source and therefore inline scripts cannot have these attributes.

Comment: @JustCarty: you are absolutely right. I think I just explained it in a confusing way :) Thanks for the feedback! I will edit my answer to make it more clear when I get the chance.